# storing struct variable from function to local struct variable

Tags: c++, struct

typenid is a struct that is defined in a class Queue, queue.h

```
struct typenid{
     typenid() : src_type(0), src_id(0){}
     uint32_t src_type;
     uint32_t src_id;
     } node_details;
```

The following is a type of class in my event driven simulator.

```
class FindNextHopEvent : public event {
    public:
    FindNextHopEvent(double time, Packet *packet, Queue::typenid node_details ); 
    ~FindNextHopEvent();
    void process_event();
    Packet *packet;
    Queue::typenid local_node_details; // should get the value of node_details
};
```

I want to use the node_details struct inside process_event() but I don't want to pass it as a parameter (due to various reason). Is there a way for local_node_details (a struct similar to node_details) to capture the value of node_details,so that I can access it in process_event() ? If so how can i do it. If I declare local_node_details as a pointer then I can use "this" operator but for structs how can I do it.

This is how my current definition looks like.

```
FindNextHopEvent::FindNextHopEvent(
   double time,
   Packet *packet,
   Queue::typenid node_details
   ): event(NEXT_HOP_EVENT, time) {
 this->packet = packet;
 Queue::typenid local_node_details= node_details;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's exactly the issue with the implementation you have right now where you pass `node_details` to the ctor and then copy it in your member variable? You can access `local_node_detail` in `process_event()` already.

Comment: In what way is the current definition not working?

Comment: local_node_details does not have the same value given to node_details

Comment: If they're the same structure and that you're making a copy, how does that happen ? Do you modify `node_details` after passing it to the constructor in the calling code, and want these modifications to apply also to the member variable? Can you show a minimal example of how you use these?

Comment: As of now, I am not modifying node_details when passing it to constructor. I do want them to apply the modification, if I do. I have a large code base, I will try to show a minimal example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, by using *references*. Pass a *reference* to the structure to the `FindNextHopEvent` constructor instead, and make your `local_node_details` structure be a reference, then you can do it:

```
class FindNextHopEvent : public event {
    Queue::typenid& local_node_details;
    //            ^
    //            |
    // Note use of ampersand to make it a reference

    ...
};

...

//               Note use of ampersand to make it a reference
//                                                          |
//                                                          v
FindNextHopEvent(double time, Packet *packet, Queue::typenid& node_details )
    // Use constructor initializer list to initialize references
    : ..., local_node_details(node_details)
{ ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But even now, when I try to access local_node_details from process_event() I am still not getting the correct values. Any ideas ?

Comment: To be more precise, printing local_node_details.dst_type in the constructor has the correct value. But when I print the same in the process event, it shows a different value.

Comment: @user2532296 Are you passing a reference to the correct structure to the constructor?

Comment: This is what I use.    ' event(NEXT_HOP_EVENT, time), local_node_details(node_details) {
    this->packet = packet; //print the values
    }'

Comment: @user2532296 Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to include it?

Comment: Sure I am doing it now. Thanks